# Omniauth using Twitter not storing some values after user creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I followed the Ruby on Rails Tutorial book and created my own authentication and signup system. I now am trying to replace that with Omniauth using Twitter authentication.

I followed all the steps in the railscast and it works, but now I'm trying to save a couple more user info fields upon user creation and they aren't saving. Here's the code to create the user:

```
  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
      user.provider = auth["provider"]
      user.uid = auth["uid"]
      user.name = auth["user_info"]["name"]
      user.email = auth["user_info"]["email"]
      user.time_zone = auth["user_info"]["time_zone"]
    end
  end
```

and here's my code for current_user if needed:

```
 def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
```

Also, where can I find a list of user info I can get from a user signing in using twitter? I need a couple other pieces of info and can't seem to find it.

Thanks!

Comment: you can look at `auth.inspect` to see exactly what twitter is sending back.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is twitter doesn't allow you to grab their email address.